# Ansible: split a dictionary with list values to a list of dictionaries with a single item from the list as value

Tags: dictionary, ansible, data-manipulation

I need to convert a dictionary with list values into a list of dictionaries.

Given:

```
my_dict:
  key1: ["111", "222"]
  key2: ["444", "555"]
```

Desired output:

```
my_list:
 - key1: "111"
   key2: "444"
 - key1: "222"
   key2: "555"
```

What I've tried:

```
  - set_fact:
      my_list: "{{ my_list | default([]) + [{item.0.key: item.1}] }}"
    loop: "{{ my_dict | dict2items | subelements('value') }}"
```

And what I've got:

```
[
            {
                "key1": "111"
            },
            {
                "key1": "222"
            },
            {
                "key2": "444"
            },
            {
                "key2": "555"
            } 
        ]
```

Thankful for any help and suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the keys and values of the dictionary first

```yaml
keys: "{{ my_dict.keys()|list }}"
vals: "{{ my_dict.values()|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
keys: [key1, key2]
vals:
  - ['111', '222']
  - ['444', '555']
```

[Transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72143872/how-can-i-alternate-the-elements-of-multiple-lists-in-ansible/72144513#72144513) the values

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        tvals: "{{ tvals|d(vals.0)|zip(item)|map('flatten') }}"
      loop: "{{ vals[1:] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
tvals:
  - ['111', '444']
  - ['222', '555']
```

Create the list of the dictionaries

```yaml
my_list: "{{ tvals|map('zip', keys)|
                   map('map', 'reverse')|
                   map('community.general.dict')|
                   list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
my_list:
  - key1: '111'
    key2: '444'
  - key1: '222'
    key2: '555'
```

---

Notes

1. Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_dict:
      key1: ["111", "222"]
      key2: ["444", "555"]
    keys: "{{ my_dict.keys()|list }}"
    vals: "{{ my_dict.values()|list }}"
    my_list: "{{ tvals|map('zip', keys)|
                       map('map', 'reverse')|
                       map('community.general.dict')|
                       list }}"
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        tvals: "{{ tvals|d(vals.0)|zip(item)|map('flatten') }}"
      loop: "{{ vals[1:] }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_list
```

2. You can use a [custom filer to transpose the matrix](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/blob/master/filter_plugins/numpy_filters/numpy.py). For example,

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/numpy.py 
# All rights reserved (c) 2022, Vladimir Botka <vbotka@gmail.com>
# Simplified BSD License, https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause

from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
__metaclass__ = type

from ansible.errors import AnsibleFilterError
from ansible.module_utils.common._collections_compat import Sequence

import json
import numpy


def numpy_transpose(arr):
    if not isinstance(arr, Sequence):
        raise AnsibleFilterError('First argument for numpy_transpose must be list. %s is %s' %
                                 (arr, type(arr)))
    arr1 = numpy.array(arr)
    arr2 = arr1.transpose()
    return json.dumps(arr2.tolist())


class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible wrappers for Python NumPy methods '''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'numpy_transpose': numpy_transpose,
        }
```

Then you can avoid iteration. For example, the playbook below gives the same result

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_dict:
      key1: ["111", "222"]
      key2: ["444", "555"]
    keys: "{{ my_dict.keys()|list }}"
    vals: "{{ my_dict.values()|list }}"
    tvals: "{{ vals|numpy_transpose()|from_yaml }}"
    my_list: "{{ tvals|map('zip', keys)|
                       map('map', 'reverse')|
                       map('community.general.dict')|
                       list }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_list
```

3. Transposing explained

Let's start with the matrix 2x2

```yaml
vals:
  - ['111', '222']
  - ['444', '555']
```

The task below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        tvals: "{{ tvals|d(vals.0)|zip(item) }}"
      loop: "{{ vals[1:] }}"
```

gives step by step:

a) Before the iteration starts the variable *tvals* is assigned the default value *vals.0*

```yaml
vals.0: ['111', '222']
```

b) The task iterates the list *vals[1:]*. These are all lines in the array except the first one

```yaml
vals[1:]:
  - ['444', '555']
```

c) The first, and the only one, iteration zip the first and the second line. This is the result

```yaml
vals.0|zip(vals.1):
  - ['111', '444']
  - ['222', '555']
```

Let's proceed with matrix 3x3

```yaml
vals:
  - ['111', '222', '333']
  - ['444', '555', '666']
  - ['777', '888', '999']
```

The task below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        tvals: "{{ tvals|d(vals.0)|zip(item)|map('flatten') }}"
      loop: "{{ vals[1:] }}"
```

gives step by step:

a) Before the iteration starts the variable *tvals* is assigned the default value *vals.0*

```yaml
vals.0: ['111', '222', '333']
```

b) The task iterates the list *vals[1:]*

```yaml
vals[1:]:
  - ['444', '555', '666']
  - ['777', '888', '999']
```

c) The first iteration zip the first and the second line, and assigns it to *tvals*. The filer *flatten* has no effect on the lines

```yaml
vals.0|zip(vals.1)|map('flatten'):
  - ['111', '444']
  - ['222', '555']
  - ['333', '666']
```

d) The next iteration zip *tvals* and the third line

```yaml
  tvals|zip(vals.2):
    - - ['111', '444']
      - '777'
    - - ['222', '555']
      - '888'
    - - ['333', '666']
      - '999
```

e) The lines must be flattened. This is the result

```yaml
tvals|zip(vals.2)|map('flatten'):
  - ['111', '444', '777']
  - ['222', '555', '888']
  - ['333', '666', '999']
```

Comment: thank you so much! Transposing values is beautiful but so difficult for me to understand!:)

Comment: I added an explanation of how to transpose a matrix. You're welcome!

Comment: Wow, thank you! Now I am really determined to understand transposition!